# Drupal Website to iPhone Webservice API in XML Format

Tags: iphone, drupal, web

We have our clients website in Drupal at present, for which we needs to create an iPhone App.

So any ideas on how to do that?

Is there any ready made available plug-ins or modules which we can use to generate Category / Articles XMLs directly from database, without much custom code n its headache?

All your suggestions are most welcome..

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You should start with "Services" module, which will allow you to communicate your website with external websites or applications.
Also, you will need a way to communicate with Drupal. We're using XMLRPC, but you can use JSON, Rest...up to you.

Here you have an starting point: http://www.zivtech.com/blog/simplest-drupal-iphone-app

Services implements the most common used methods for Drupal. Which are node saving/load, comments and users. If you need extra functionality, you will need to create a custom module (rather easy).
You can test all the calls with the Services tab in the Drupal website. Just remember to set the permissions.

There is also a Drupal-iOS SDK, which does almost everything I told you, but uses plist instead. https://github.com/seanhellwig/drupal-ios-sdk

Comment: i don't need feature to add contents/comments from iphone, just needs my contents to display on screen only(only fetch db records), from database..

Comment: Then you will need to use the node_load method within module services (which is essentially a node_load call for Drupal), and play with that.

Comment: You should link to the original ios sdk not a fork. https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk